# Trying to construct an elliptic curve pairing (Tate) example. Can someone help me figure out where my mistake is?

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography, torsion-groups, trace-map

I'm trying to construct an example of the Tate pairing, but for some reason I'm not getting the bilinearity property that I should be getting. Here's my setup:

Take $q=29$ and $$E/\mathbb{F}_q : y^2 = x^3 + 21x $$

$E$ has $26$ points, and using $r = 13$ for the $r$-torsion, we have embedding degree $k = 3$.

Pick a point in the $r$-torsion, $P = (28,6)$.

Next we extend $E$ to $E/\mathbb{F}_{q^k}$ by creating 
$$\mathbb{F}_{q^k} := \mathbb{F}_q(u)$$
where $$u^3+u+4 \equiv 0$$
because that polynomial is irreducible mod $29$.

$E/\mathbb{F}_{q^k}$ has $24674$ elements, so take $h=\frac{24674}{r^2} = 146$. Next we pick any random point on $E/\mathbb{F}_{q^k}$, call it $Q$. We can send $Q$ to the trace-zero subgroup of the $r$-torsion by multiplying it by $h$ (this brings it into the $r$-torsion), and then applying the anti-trace map

$$Q := k*Q - \text{Trace}(Q)$$

---

From here, I'm just using a code for Miller's algorithm that I found [here](http://craigcostello.com.au/pairings/beginners/5-3-1-TateWeilMiller.txt). The code's example works. My issue is that when I compute the Tate pairing for $P$ and $Q$, I don't get bilinearity...

I'm happy to post my full code if anyone's willing to take a look. It's written in Magma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex, there is a problem in all the magma codes posted in Pairings by Craig Costello.

I bet you didn't get the bilinearity because in fADD function there is a mistake. Change this line `v:=F!(x-(lambda^2-P[1]-P[2]));` with `v:=F!(x-(lambda^2-P[1]-Q[1]));`

That's the correct way to get the vertical line equation. Unfortunately the same mistake is present in all the other magma code samples in that paper.

Btw, I've spent 2 days to figure it out that mistake .. But, I am happy now.

Comment: Wow, thank you so so so much. I'll give this a shot!

Comment: No problem. If it worked you could also accept this answer :)